# Java DAO design pattern category?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Which category (Creational, Structural or Behavioral) does a Java DAO design pattern falls into?

Comment: What are those categories? Why do you think DAOs fall under one of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java DAO design pattern is a part of layered architecture and single Responsibility problem where dao should only handle the DB related stuff.

It can not be classified under java design pattern i.e Creational, Structural or Behavioral

Answer (score 7):

DAO is Data access object to retrieve and store data. DAO's can be combined with other design patterns such as MVC(Model View Controller) where the DAO's can act as the models. DAO is pretty similar to models and POJO(Plain Old Java Object).

DAO is not a design pattern in itself (though some consider it to be a J2EE design pattern) but it can be used to implement other design patterns. So you cannot classify it in the three major categories of design patterns.

From Wikipedia :

> In computer software, a data access object (DAO) is an object that
>   provides an abstract interface to some type of database or other
>   persistence mechanism. By mapping application calls to the persistence
>   layer, DAO provide some specific data operations without exposing
>   details of the database. This isolation supports the Single
>   responsibility principle. It separates what data accesses the
>   application needs, in terms of domain-specific objects and data types
>   (the public interface of the DAO), from how these needs can be
>   satisfied with a specific DBMS, database schema, etc. (the
>   implementation of the DAO).

Comment: After going through this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm I had this doubt :)

Comment: Yes. They have a separate example for this DAO. It is just a name for these special classes.

Comment: In MVC a model represents the data that a view shows. It does not implement data retrieval nor data persist logic. If you have a very simple architecture the controller will be the component responsible for that. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller and the definition of a DAO http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Why do you say that DAO is not a design pattern? It has been described in various sources as a design pattern. Take for example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object and this book http://www.amazon.com/J2EE-Design-Patterns-William-Crawford/dp/0596004273/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1451722560&sr=1-3&keywords=J2EE+design+patterns+in+books

Comment: Design patterns are broadly classified into Creational, Behaviorial and Structural. DAO does not fall in that category. It is a type of object similar to beans, models and POJO's. Is model or bean or POJO a designe pattern in itself ? No. It is combined with others to make another design pattern.